# DataAnnotations localization message issue for RegEx validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, data-annotations

I have a problem with the validation message for Regular expression. Localised messages appear everywhere except for one field below:

```
    [LocalizedDisplayName("LblWordCount", NameResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages.Messages))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorFieldRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages.Messages))]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "", ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorDigitsOnly", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages.Messages))]
    public Int32 WordCount { get; set; }
```

It doesn't matter what I put in the resx file for "ErrorDigitsOnly" - the default message always kicks in: "The value 'zxzza1' is not valid for Word Count." For instance - message for the [Required] appears correctly.

Any suggestions for that?

Cheers,
303

I have checked the code for spelling mistakes but couldn't find any.

Comment: Remove `ErrorMessage = ""` from the attribute worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I actually ran across a similar situation myself.
Have you tried setting the wordcount validation in another class instead of using the regex pattern in the DataAnnotation Attribute?

For example -

```
  public class EmailAttribute: RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public EmailAttribute() : base(@"[^@\.]+(\.[^@\.]+)*@[^@\.]+(\.[^@\.]+)?(\.[^@\.]{2,})")
    {
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return Resources.Resources.emailValidation;
    }
}
```

You can then use the attribute like so -

```
    [CustomRequired]
    [Email]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

The advantages of using it this way means that you get strong typing on your resources and it also allows you to write neater validation classes.

Hope it helps!